# PyInstaller, generate binary file to ARM32

Tags: linux, arm, pyinstaller, binaryfiles

I have an image in virtualbox with "xubuntu-22.04.03-desktop-amd64.iso". In this machine I have installed python3.7, pyinstall and others libs,
[Arquitecture of my virtualbox image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjTxB.png).

Now, I have an application written in python 3.7 and I need to generate a binary file from my application to a ARM32 arquitecture using pyinstaller.

At this moment I´m able to generate the binary file of my application and the binary file is working. The problem is that I need to execute this binary file within an ARM32 arquitecture system. I tried to execute it but I have the next error: "cannot execute binary file".

This is the command that I´m using to generate the binary file:

> **pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --add-data "./data1:data1/" --add-data "./data2:data2/" --add-data "./data3:data3/" --add-data "./data4:data4/" --add-data "./data5:data5/" --add-data "./data6.py:./" --hidden-import uuid --hidden-import "web3" --hidden-import "sqlite3" --hidden-import "pydantic" --hidden-import "devtools" --hidden-import "attributedict.collections" "./menu.py"**

I have read this problem can be by generate the binary file in a different arquitecture than ARM32.

How could I generate this binary file to works in ARM32.

Thank you for help.